# How can I download TfvcTemplate.12.xaml?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I create a build definition .In process tab when I select the Default Template and when I wan download it i get an error[image].

what is the problem?
I install tfs2013 on my local pc that has win7 Ultimate 64 Os with  vs2013 update 4

**Solution**
I install tfs on a server and my problem resolved

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @ds19 vs2013 update 4

Comment: Why do you have TFS installed locally?

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down this problem, try the following actions:

1. Check whether the **Activitylog** contains any clues:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx
2. Try another computer with VS2013 installed and connected to your TFS
   server.
3. Clear the TFS cache by going into default **C:\ {User Profile Folder}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache** and VS cache in appdata folder

By the way, we usually don’t install TFS sever on our dev machine. It’s just a server, you can connect it through VS on other machines. I suggest you could install it on your Virtual Machine to make sure the environment is clean.